# How can I solve performance problems of Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 13.04

I was using 12.04. I upgraded to 12.10 and then to 13.04 on the day 13.04 was released. I have also installed GNOME 3.8 with gdm. I'm facing some problems using 13.04. It takes a lot of time to boot up. Almost double than 12.04. Similarly, it takes a lot of time to load the desktop. Initially, I was having problems with GNOME 3.8.2 (staging release), so I purged those ppas and downgraded to 3.8. Sometimes my sound card doesn't work. I also have a 2 GB ATI Graphics Card which I have kept off using vgaswitcheroo. Sometimes 13.04 boot up properly. It stops at ubuntu splash screen. Sometimes it doesn't shut down. I have to manually use `init 0`  to do that.

On startup, I get this message - `lis3lv02d` no such sensor found.

I didn't face any such problems in 12.04. Was there some problem with upgrade? or Ubuntu 13.04 is really buggy? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's generally regarded that the best way to perform an upgrade from one release to another, is to do a fresh install. Upgrading the way you have invites issues such as the one you have.

If you can, do a fresh install - don't forget to back up your ~/home files first. That will mean you'll get the best install possible.

Hope that helps.